# window.location.assign goes to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code - index.php which displays login screen, and editor.php which is site admin.

Now, this admin has also logout link, which should work like this:

- click link
- call js logout()
- which will call logout.php via ajax, which will authentication info from cookies
- success handler redirects to login screen (index.php). I could also redirect to same page which checks auth info and will redirect to login screen also.

But actually it works like this:

- first 3 are same
- success handler redirects to same page (editor.php - Chrome console shows "Navigated to ...editor.php") though do window.location.assign('index.php'). editor.php is not aware that user is not authenticated any more and still shows the admin page. When I refresh the page, then editor.php redirects correctly to index.php

I know it is a bit odd way to handle logout routine, don't critisize the design please :) I don't want to know the correct way to do this but understand:

1. why browser decides that location.assign('index.php') should
   actually be 'editor.php' (redirect cache? After login there is redirect index.php -> editor.php). I have tried full URL also
2. why editor.php is not actually reloading itself (cache?)

html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="logout(); return false;">logout</a>
```

js:

```
function logout() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "logout.php",
        // simplified success handler
        success : function(msg) {
            // will eventually redirect to right place
            window.location.assign('index.php');
            //window.location.reload(); // NOTE this instead of assign works correctly
        }
    });
}
```

Note that if I replace location.assign with location.reload, it behaves correctly.

Comment: Why don't you try window.location.href='/logout.php'

Comment: You mean `window.location.href = '/index.php'`? Tried that too, same.

Comment: just past **window.location.href = '/index.php'** in logout() and comment your ajax call check whether it is working or not ?